Cant render volume shader in EEVEE at blender 4.2
I'm just simple: create a new file, add a block, set a volume scattering shader for the block, and connect the shader output to the volume.
Then in rendering mode, EEVEE cannot render and the blocks become transparent. Under Cycles rendering, everything is normal.
I have tried multiple times but cannot render properly under Blender 4.2. I switched back to Blender 3.6 and everything returned to normal. What's going on?
In addition, I heard that EEVEE can choose between EEVEE or EEVEE NEXT in version 4.2. Why don't I have a switching option here?
https://imgur.com/a/5rPqx64 (Sorry about big gif file)

Where did you hear that you can switch? I know there were earlier versions of EEVEE Next in previous experimental or alpha builds of Blender where you could switch between them, but those were no official stable releases and just for testing and debugging (there it was clearly named "Next" at the end, while now it is just "EEVEE" because it replaced the old one). But about your problem: it would really help if you showed your render settings under Volumes (especially the Custom Range settings I guess), because with my default settings it simply works without any problems.

@GordonBrinkmann       Custom Rang   is the default 0.1-100.Even if I close it, the volume will not be rendered correctly.
